# How can we reset the data and state of the mutation in RTK query , like reset function in React Query for mutation?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using RTK query with Redux Tool kit for the React project. The table rows are updated with "updateProductCategory" function provided by RTK mutation. But after the update of each table row, "updateProductCategoryResult" is filled with data and state of that updated row(that means, if the update is successful , then "isSuccess" = true).

So for the next update, as "isSuccess" mutation state is "true" , the SnackBar (i.e toaster) will popup when the modal form to edit row is opened (before the actual edit occurs). So, to avoid such unwanted Snack Bar pop up, I want to reset the data and state of mutation result after mutation occurs,i.e. "updateProductCategoryResult" to have isSuccess = false, isError = false .

Basically I need reset() function like in React Query mutation.

I searched into the RTK query document , but couldn't found any thing related to reset of mutation state and data.

Code:

```
//State to open SnackBar
const [snackBarProps, setSnackBarProps] = useState({
    alertType: "",
    message: "",
  });

// Hooks to fetch product category
const { data = [], isFetching } = useGetProductCategoryQuery(queryBody);

//Hook to update product category
const [updateProductCategory, updateProductCategoryResult] = useUpdateProductCategoryMutation();

// SnackBar while "Updating Category".
// Bug occured here, as "updateProductCategoryResult.isSuccess" will be  
// true after every successful update, which changes the "snackBarProps" 
// state by calling "setSnackBarProps" and pops the Snack Bar when just 
// opening the modal to edit row data of the table.

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updateProductCategoryResult.isError) {
      setSnackBarProps({
        alertType: "error",
        message: "Updating Product Category Failed !!!",
      });
    }

    if (updateProductCategoryResult.isSuccess) {
      setSnackBarProps({
        alertType: "success",
        message: "Updated Product Category Successfully !!!",
      });

      dispatch(closeModal());
    }

    return () => {
      setSnackBarProps({
        alertType: "",
        message: "",
      });
    };
  }, [updateProductCategoryResult, isFetching]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different dependency array - right now it is triggering on every change of `updateProductCategoryResult` - but you want it to trigger if `isError` or `isSuccess` change:

```js
 [updateProductCategoryResult.isError, updateProductCategoryResult.isSuccess, isFetching]);
```

Comment: I think I ran with the similar issue after using different dependency array.  After successful mutation ,  `updateProductCategoryResult.isSuccess` would be `true`. So, now for every render , the second `if ` condition in above code `useEffect` becomes successful and executes the code inside it. But I want to avoid it. So, it would be really easy if there is a way to make `updateProductCategoryResult.isSuccess` to be `false` after receiving result from mutation.

Comment: You are misunderstanding dependency arrays. The code in the useEffect will only run if a value in the dependency array changes. So as long as isError, isSuccess and isChanging do not change, your effect will never re-run.
Give this a read: (yes, it is rather long but worth it!) https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: I had used `isFetching` as a dependency array , so it was re-running `useEffect` . Now i have removed it and only used `updateProductCategoryResult` as a dependency array. So its woking properly. The article was quite an eye opening towards the `useEffect`. Thank You.

Comment: @phry is there any way to update the mutation cache anyway.

Comment: @Irfanwani no. Mutations are there to change things on the server and look at the response for a brief moment, not for long-term data storage. So it doesn't make any sense to update them.